# Chrome, Linux Mint, Low FPS in games

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, chrome, games

I'm running Linux Mint 16 on a desktop computer with Nvidia GeForce GTX 550 Ti (driver 331.20, older driver also has same problems) graphics, and have been using the current stable version of Chrome. After reboots and for some  amount of time if I play games such as Team Fortress 2, Minecraft, and other native running games (no Wine) I get good FPS (100-150) and the games run smooth. But at some point my FPS drops to 20 when the games start and drop to around 9 FPS. After closing the game and relaunching same problems, but sometimes I have exited Chrome (and the background processes) and relaunched both Chrome and the game and my FPS goes back to normal. This is not always the case, some times exiting Chrome dose not work and I have to restart to come back to normal FPS.

What may cause this? Chrome is one possible cause, but something else is causing problems too.

Comment: are you running out of memory?

Comment: I have 12GB of memory and never seem to get over 6GB when running a lot of stuff and a game open. But I have submissions that may be using up the video memory or something.